# Runtime Permission Handling

Tags: android, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

Is it necessary to include required permissions(For ex-WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)  in manifest file if i am using run time permission manager for compileSdkVersion 24 and minSdkVersion is 23?

Comment: Yeah otherwise it will give an error

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: Yes, you should keep them in the manifest too. Check my library to handle runtime permissions easily. https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all permissions are to be explicitly declared in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file regardless of implemented them as Runtime permission or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You need to include all permission in `manifest.xml` file even You use it in run time else it will not run. You can find more information about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous)
. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You need to declare required permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

Permission modal only works for marshmallow and above platforms.

To support version smaller than  marshmallow, you need to declare them.